# Amplify Flutter S3 file download using Cognito

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I was trying to access S3 bucket protected contents from Flutter Amplify framework. I have configures Auth and Storage plugins in Amplify by following Amplify docs. But I was receiving access denied exception upon file download.

Exception:

> StorageException(message: Something went wrong with your AWS S3 Storage download file operation, recoverySuggestion: See attached exception for more information and suggestions, underlyingException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: F4297FA684QR5N34), S3 Extended Request ID: xKzvpdGmVuC+OErI5b9fVvqeZClQ0sMypw309F9Tcsx+948Q+s1ntkWigZxBlBhiCynaMV3OpcQ=)

Persmissions for IAM user
[image]

Comment: Have you given the IAM user the relative permissions to download files from that S3 bucket?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes. Attached permission list of IAM user in the original question.

Comment: Please take 5 minutes and fully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - we need more code unfortunately!

Comment: any updates on this?